Limited results when BeautifulSoup Loop titles from an html span class
# Import packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify url: url
url = 'https://www.nts.live/shows'

# Package the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

# Extracts the response as html: html_doc
html_doc = r.text

# Create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML: soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
empty_list = []

spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'title-wrapper'})

for span in spans:
    empty_list.append(span.text)

print(empty_list)

Problem
This loop only returns the first 13 titles from the url 'https://www.nts.live/shows'
when there are much more titles in this url.
Current Result
['100 Elements w/ YL ', '1080P w/ HD', '143 RADIO w/ SOSUPERSAM', '150 Session', '239EF', '3XL', '404 w/ Ifeoluwa', '454 Presents: Florida Man FM', '5 GATE TEMPLE', '80s Rampwalk ', '8ULENTINA', '99Ginger']

Question
Do you know why the results are limited?

Are the rest dynamically loaded? You might need selenium.

The problem is likely because you are using requests, which cannot process javascript.

Thanks John! Would you know a package which can process javascript?

@CrazyChucky yes probably the url I shared might add or remove some titles, however, my code is not being able to retrieve the current number of titles.

You can get everything with Selenium, which runs an actual web browser: Parsing data scraped from Javascript rendered webpage with python

why was this closed? it can and is better  done without selenium

@GTK How would you do that? The linked question is still accepting answers.

(Or if you know of an answered question that's better, perhaps raise a flag?)

@CrazyChucky This particular site uses ajax, you can retrieve the remaining shows from the endpoint.

Aha, good catch! Voted to reopen.

Hi @GTK ,
Thanks! Do you have any suggestions of solving this without using Selenium?

@pepperjohn I was in the middle of writing an answer (requests & bs4) when this was closed.

ahh I understand, would it be possible to post your answer as a comment?

@pepperjohn I don't know why this question was closed. it can be solved without the overhead selenium brings. The first thing to check when web scraping is whether you can get the underlying API. In this case here is the API
it indicates a total count of 1509 in the resultset and a limit of 12 per page.
using this info, you can loop through the pages and get all your data. Here is the url to use for the requests. Also make sure to include the payload ajax=true.
